# How to name Google Map Marker Icon types using two words?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm developing a Google map to display job locations using custom Marker Icons.

Here's a snippet of the code that I am using to set up the variable 'markerIcon' and the 'type' name (**Administrative**):

BEFORE

```js
var markerIcon = {
        Administrative: {
        url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
        // scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(80, 80),
        // origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        // anchor: new google.maps.Point(32,65),
        // labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(40,33)
        }
      };
```

This is fine, so here's a snippet that doesn't work with the var 'type' name **Administrative and Clerical**:

AFTER

```js
var markerIcon = {
            Administrative and Clerical: {
            url: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png'
            // scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(80, 80),
            // origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            // anchor: new google.maps.Point(32,65),
            // labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(40,33)
            }
          };
```

This is the problem I am experiencing. The use of more than one word and with spaces.

Below is the function that creates the marker:

```js
function createMarker(latlng, name, company, address, type, jobdesc) {
  var jobButton = "<a class='btn btn-success btn-sm mt-2' role='button' href='/public/job_details_demo.php?" + "title=" + name + "'" + "target='_blank'>View Job" + "</a>";
  var html = "<h5 class='mb-0'>" + name + "</h5>" + "<h6 class='mb-0'>" + company + "</h6>" + "<p><b>" + address + "</b></p>" + "<b>Job Details:</b></br>" + jobdesc + "</p>" + jobButton;
  var icon = markerIcon[type] || {};
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map,
     position: latlng,
     icon: icon.url
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
  infoWindow.setContent(html);
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
```

To display the icons, I query the database to retrieve the 'jobsector_name' AS type using SQL. This works fine and the Marker Icons show up.

However, I need to use more than one word for the jobsector names, for example, 'Administrative and Clerical'. When I change the type to this name in the database and the Marker Icon name, the markers don't show, and no errors are shown in the Chrome console.

My question is, how do I solve the problem of using two or more words for the Marker Icon type names?

I've tried special characters like %20, but unsurprisingly the code hates any special characters. I've also tried referencing numbers, but they don't show and I've tried concatenating two variables, but don't know how to reference a variable inside another variable for this type of operation.

Comment: How did you try to make the "multiple word description" icons?  Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: @geocodezip. Thank you for your reply. My code uses a Google Map API key, so I can't provide the complete and verifiable working code. However, I will add the 'before and after' code examples so you can see where I make the "multiple word descriptions".

Comment: If that concerns you provide your [mcve] (that you tested) with the key redacted.

Comment: @geocodezip. The map will not work without the key!

Comment: I have keys that I can use (if you provide the code that exhibits the issue)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm also using a local database, which won't show the markers if I provide the complete code here. How else can I exhibit the issue?

Comment: Capture a small set of sample data, make a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (without requiring the database).

Comment: I don't want to sound ungrateful but for me to provide a complete and verifiable example would be a lengthy process. My code uses many php includes. I've seen other questions regarding issues with Google Map markers, and they've not had to produce a complete and verifiable example. I would be happy to investigate any leads that you can provide related to the problem I have, if you have any idea that is?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
I added '_' underscores between each word (both in the MarkerIcon type and database column values) and then used PHP command 'str_replace', when displaying the name on the page.

```
$jobsector = str_replace("_", " ", $row['jobsector_name']);
```

[PHP Manual - str_replace — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)